# Discord.js slash command permission system not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, permissions, discord, discord.js

This is the main code for the permission setting.

```js
const run = (client) => __awaiter(void 0, void 0, void 0, function* () {
    const commandFiles = glob_1.default.sync(process.cwd() + "/src/commands/**/*{.ts,.js}");
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(config_json_1.default.guildId);
    commandFiles.map(value => {
        Promise.resolve().then(() => __importStar(require(value))).then((file) => __awaiter(void 0, void 0, void 0, function* () {
            exports.commands.set(file.info.name, file);
            const command = yield guild.commands.create(file.info);
            if (file.permission == undefined || file.permission == "@everyone")
                return;
            const json = (file.permission == "admin" ? {
                id: config_json_1.default.adminRole,
                permission: true,
                type: "ROLE"
            } : {
                id: config_json_1.default.freelancerRole,
                permission: true,
                type: "ROLE"
            });
            command.permissions.add({
                permissions: [json]
            });
        }));
    });
```

I have commissioned a dev for a discord bot and everything is working apart from the fact that anybody can use any command. He has a custom permission system that sets it with the above method. However, this does not work. I have debugged the config role ids, file.permission is set and he is positive it works. File.permission is set with `exports.permission = "admin";` in a command file and defaultpermission is true.

Comment: This code shows how permissions are defined. You should edit your question and add the part of the code that shows how permissions are evaluated at the time of running a command.

Answer (score 0):

Discord doesn't have permission called `admin`, you have to use `ADMINISTRATOR` permission instead!

Comment: Thanks, but it's going off role permissions not actual discord permissions. The thing is "admin" is just a plain text string he uses to check whether to use adminRole or freelancerRole. He forwards the string in the command file to the permission file so it knows what role to add permission to.